# C/C++ Cast to const weirdness

Tags: c++, c, casting, constants

I have a function declared as:

```
int myFunction(const float** ppArr, const int n, const int m);
```

and when I call it like so:

```
float** ppArr = new float*[5];
// Some initialization of ppArr

int result = myFunction(ppArr, 5, 128);  <<<< Error
```

and the error is (VS 2008 Express):

```
error C2664: 'Test_myFunction.cpp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float **' to 'const float **'
```

WTF? I'm casting a float** to const float**. What could possibly go wrong with that ? :/

Edit: Thank you for incredibly fast responses!!! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read ["Why am I getting an error converting a Foo** → Foo const**?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17) at C++ FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

As strange as it seems, it could actually reduce const-correctness in certain obscure cases, allowing you to modify a const object indirectly.

See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17 for the full details.

What you can do is convert `Foo**` to `Foo const* const*` as that doesn't leave any back doors open.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an important observation to the mostly valid answers: things are different for C and C++. Whereas the trick works in C++ with `Foo const* const*` this doesn't work in C, it wouldn't accept this and throw a warning.

In C you'd have to go more complicated ways if you want to have a typesafe cast to `Foo const* const*`.

Comment: I couldn't find a rationale why C (even C11), as opposed to C++, didn't allow implicit cast of `Foo **` to `Foo const *const *`. Do you happen to know that?

Comment: I have vague memory that the committee considered that imposing implementing such a rule would be too complicated for straight forward compiler implementations. (Well, have such beasts ever existed?) In any case this is a real restriction in C and makes the use of `const` almost impractical for multi-dimensional function parameters.

Comment: This makes me want to cry. It's a real, objective deficiency. I've never written a compiler, but I don't see what's so complicated in allowing adding chains of any length of implicitly added `const`, as opposed to only length <= 1.

Answer (score 0):

`float**` cannot be converted into `const float**`.

It can be converted into `float* const*` and `const float* const*` . Like this:

```
void f(float* const* p) {}

void h(const float* const* p) {}

int main() {
    float** p= new float*[5];
    f(p);
    h(p);
}
```

Compile it with GCC: http://ideone.com/RrIXl

Comment: @David: Other answer explains that. I'm just being lazy :P